# Direct product of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $n = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. I am trying to show that: $$\mathbb{Z}_n[X] \cong \mathbb{Z}_p[X] \times \mathbb{Z}_q[X].$$

Would it suffice to say that $\rho(np) = \rho(n)\rho(p)$?

I am not sure how to set up the proof, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, first you are going to have to define what $\rho$ is, and if $\rho$ has domain $\Bbb Z_n[x]$ then $\rho(n)=0$, so that doesn't get you very far. I imagine you are not writing down very clearly what you mean. Take another look and try again!

Comment: It's essentially chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Find maps $\mathbb Z[X]\to Z_m[X]$ and $\mathbb Z[x]\to Z_p[X]\times Z_q[X]$. Show that these two maps have the same kernel and are onto. Hence the two ranges are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

1. Make sure you understand why for distinct prime numbers $p$ and $q$, $\mathbb{Z}/pq \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Try to show more generally that if for a rings $A,B,C$ you have $A \cong B \times C$, then $A[x] \cong B[x] \times C[x]$.  This should help to focus your efforts.  The actual isomorphism is almost obvious when you write everything down and think a bit.

Comment: I understand the rules and definitions, I just dont know how to formulate the proof.

Comment: Because the map $\alpha$ -> $(\rho_p(\alpha), \rho_q(\alpha))$

Comment: @Ben: As Thomas has mentioned 1. is precisely the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  For 2. you need to take a polynomial over a product $B \times C$ and regard it as a polynomial over $B$ together with a polynomial over $C$.  This is what you need to think about.